# How to use Opencart's objects and method's for custom log in functionality

Tags: methods, authentication, opencart

I just finished course of OOP PHP and currently working on integrating facebook login and sign up functionality to Opencart (2.3.0.3 version) store. What I have for now is a php script which returns me an array with user's data like first name, last name, email, etc. The main problem for me now is that it is completely unclear how to further deal with this data, namely:
1) which properties and methods to use to login and create a user
2) in which files to write code (catalog/controller/somefile or in files in the system folder)
3) how to call opencart's methods and use it's properties in different pages (how to include them to those pages)

Currently I am taking a course MVC for beginners but it looks like it isn't making it clearer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478995/how-to-become-an-opencart-guru

Answer (score 0):

The account management in OpenCart is pritty easy to use, there is a model called 'account/customer', you can find it at 'catalog/model/account/customer.php'. This model contains a function called addCustomer, you are able to create customers through this function with the right parameters.

In privious versions of OpenCart there was a library file called 'customer.php', that you could find at 'system/library/customer.php'. This class contained the functions to login etc. I just checked the source of the current version of OpenCart, but this file is gone. So it depends on what version you are using for further explaining.

Comment: I just took a look at those files as well as other topics regarding my question and found out that I lack knowledge and understanding of how opencart works on its own and how everything interacts inside that cms and it looks like I have to spend some time on that first. If it's possible, can you give links to learning materials or examples which could help me out in achieving that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Kirill What version of OpenCart are you using?

Comment: It is Opencart 2.3.0.3 currently installed